# wcf and security, authentication and ssl

Tags: asp.net, wcf

We have built a WCF service for an application and everything is working out well, using WSHttpBinding.  We now have been asked to make sure the communication between the Web Application -> WCF -> Database is secure and have been asked to use SSL.  Along with that they are requesting we make sure the WCF service can not be accessed by another application.

If we setup SSL, does that block others from trying to get in, or we do still need to setup the clientCredentialType setting on the service?  Also the entire application (site, wcf, db) will be within a company's network, so if we setup the clientCredentialType="Windows" which account is used, how does WCF know to allow the website to talk to it, which Windows account are they using, or this an account we need to setup?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSL has nothing to do with Authentication or Authorization.
It does 2 things:

- prevents third parties from intercepting your traffic.
- verifies that people are who they say they are.

The requirement "make sure the WCF service can not be accessed by another application" needs to be handled through some Authentication / Authorization mechanism. You could use Basic or Windows depending on your needs.

Since you're in the company's network, I'd attempt to use Windows Authentication. This will force clients to be authenticated through your domain, however it looks like you don't want just any domain user to have access. In this case, you need to set up either Role based authorization, or user based. Either war, you can drop a Web.config file into the same folder as the WCF service endpoint specifying what accounts are authorized. Other users will see a 401 Unauthorized.

This is the general approach I'd take.